# Download multiple file in ASP.NET or Flash

Tags: asp.net, flash, download

Is there any way to DOWNLOAD multiple files in asp.net?

Is there any way to DOWNLOAD multiple files in Flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading - means getting reply from server for certain request. You can get only 1 reply for 1 request. Saying that you cannot get several downloads by single request. However, if you want user to be able to download several files in single click you can zip files on server and get them out to user as single file.

Another option is to create flash application that will sent several download requests. Depends of what you are trying to achive.

Comment: Please describe your flash idea. Thanks